# If foldername equals "somestring", move all files in the folder one level up

Tags: files, find, move

Due to an old backup concept I have some hard drives here, that contain file structures like:

```
/1.1
/2.1
/3.1
/FOLDER.DUPLICATE.$DRIVEBENDER/1.1
/FOLDER.DUPLICATE.$DRIVEBENDER/3.1
/FOLDER.DUPLICATE.$DRIVEBENDER/4.1
/Subfolder/1.2
/Subfolder/FOLDER.DUPLICATE.$DRIVEBENDER/2.2
/Subfolder/FOLDER.DUPLICATE.$DRIVEBENDER/3.2
```

The result should equal to the original structure, so all files in a folder called `FOLDER.DUPLICATE.$DRIVEBENDER` should be moved one level higher. If the file one level higher exists, the bigger file should win.

Comment: Biggest wins? Not newest?

Comment: No, in this case really biggest wins. In the "raw" data, the sync (newest wins) worked. But as the "crash" began, some corruptet files came up and them were truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have `FOLDER.DUPLICATE.$DRIVEBENDER` directories inside other `FOLDER.DUPLICATE.$DRIVEBENDER` directories, you could do something like:

```
find . -path '*/FOLDER.DUPLICATE.$DRIVEBENDER/*' -prune -type f -print0 |
  perl -0lne '
    if (m{(.*)/FOLDER.DUPLICATE.\$DRIVEBENDER/(.*)}s) {
      $upperfile = "$1/$2";
      if (-s > -s $upperfile) {
        rename $_, $upperfile or warn "rename $_: $!\n";
      } else {
        unlink $_ or warn "unlink $_: $!\n";
      }
    }'
```

(if your `find` doesn't support `-print0`, you can replace with `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +`).